# ImageButton image not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to programmatically set image of ImageButton. 
My code is below:

```
String path="Images/1/";
path= path + string.Format("{0}", _ds.Tables[_bplp.SqlEntityX].DefaultView[0]["Photograph"]);
ImageButton1.ImageUrl = path;
```

I am saving images in my site folder Images/1 , and storing image name in database.
Problem lies when I am trying to display image in ImageButton.
Although after debugging it, path variable is taking correct path of image
     as  **"Images/1/imagename.jpg"**, but still ImageButton doesnot show image.

Also, Images folder lies at root level of website.

Comment: Should it be DefaultView[0["Photograph"]) ? Missing bracket?

Comment: path= path + string.Format("{0}", _ds.Tables[_bplp.SqlEntityX].DefaultView[0]["Photograph"]);

Comment: I had copied it incorrectly there, but this part is working fine, as I am getting image name from database

Comment: Is your page in the root folder? You are using a relative path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

replace this

```
 String path="Images/1/";
```

with

```
String path="~/Images/1/";
```

Comment: I already done that , but as I told u, I am getting correct path to image, still not loading image

Comment: did you try by hardcoding the actual path in place of Path variable?

Comment: I was not setting correct Site folder url in my webconfig file, so that is why i was getting this error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try `ResolveUrl();`

```
ImageButton1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/" + path);
```

Comment: I tried relative path too, this seems so simple, but giving me headache

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my webconfig file, I had set incorrect site folder url in that, above code is working fine now

Thanks to all